# Disable editing of Google Sheet row based on populated date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a spreadsheet and column A contains the date for when that specific row was edited.  However, I want to restrict editing of that row when the current date is greater than column A.  Effectively, past data rows cannot be edited.

Here is my current code which adds the date and the user for who edited the row:

```
    function onEdit(e) {

   var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
        cols = [3],
        colStamp = 1,
        ind = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
        if (s.getName() !== 'Log' || ind == -1) return;
   e.range.offset(0, parseInt(colStamp - cols[ind]))
        .setValue(e.value ? Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM/dd/YYYY") : null);

   s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 7).setValue(Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername());
}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: The easiest option would be a [daily trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) (runs at 12 midnight) that based on the value in Column A sets [protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()) for that row.